# Can stratified sampling be done on 2 continous variable together? If yes How?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, sampling, sklearn-pandas

I have 2 continuous variables on which stratified sampling needs to be done. I have to make 10 equal samples from this data. How can this be done

I know there is train_test_split which can be used for stratified sampling, but it divides in 2 2 samples only. how can this be done for 10 samples

Comment: Try `StratifiedKFold` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html

Comment: I don't want k fold cross validation.